# Show that $f$ is not continuous at (0,0) and is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but the restritions to straight line in $\mathbb{r}^2$ is cont.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

> if $f(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4}$ and $f(0,0)=0$ show that $f$ is not continuous at (0,0) and is bounded on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but the restritions to straight line in $\mathbb{r}^2$ is cont.

My attempt:
By changing the numerator and denominator a bit we get the function of the form $f(x,y)=\frac{z}{z^2+1}$ where $z=\frac{x}{y^2}$ and then I take two cases where $\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{z}{z^2+1} \to 0$ and  $\lim_{z \to \infty}\frac{z}{z^2+1} \to 1$ this is how I have shown that the function is bounded.

Now the next thing that I have to show is that the function is discontinuous at $(0,0)$ so we consider the line $y=x$ from here I have done that $f(x,y=x)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+x^4}$.Now,if  $lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x^3}{x^2+x^4} \to 0$ .I have got no intition as to why it would not be continuous at$(0,0)$.To prove continuity at straightline I have taken $y=mx+c$ and I have used the same tactic.Any hint to rectify my mistake would be highly appreciated.

Comment: take the limit along the curve $x=y^2$

Comment: $z/(z^2+1)\to 0$ for both $z\to 0$ and $z\to\infty$; your argument for boundedness doesn't really work because the map is not monotone.

Comment: A simple way to show boundedness would be to note that $\left|\dfrac z{1+z^2}\right|=\dfrac{|z|}{|z|^2+1}$ and that the map $x\mapsto\dfrac x{x^2+1}$ on $[0,\infty)$ is bounded below by $0$ (trivial) and above by $1/2$ (using single variable calculus tools or AM-GM on $x+1/x$ after dividing num and denom by $x$)

Comment: @Prasun Biswas: Since the function
$$
z\mapsto\frac{z}{z^2+1}
$$
is continuous, and approaches $0$ at $\infty$ and $-\infty$, it follows that the function is bounded.

Comment: @quasi: ah yes, that's a simpler proof of boundedness, although it doesn't give the actual bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear that $f$ is continuous at all points of $\mathbb{R}^2$ except possibly at $(0,0)$.

It follows that the restriction of $f$ to any line not passing through $(0,0)$ is continuous.

Next consider the restriction of $f$ to a line $L$ passing through $(0,0)$.

If $L$ is the $y$-axis, then $x=0$, so $f$ is identically $0$ on $L{\setminus}\{(0,0)\}$, hence, since we also have $f(0,0)=0$, it follows that the restriction of $f$ to $L$ is continuous.

If $L$ passes through $(0,0)$ but is not the $y$-axis, then $y=mx$ for some fixed constant $m\in\mathbb{R}$. To verify that $f$ restricted to $L$ is continuous, it suffices
to show that
$$
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x(mx)^2}{x^2+(mx)^4}=0
$$
You should have no trouble with that.

Finally, to verify that $f$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$, note that if $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along the curve $x=y^2$, the limit reduces to
$$
\lim_{y\to 0}\frac{y^4}{2y^4}
$$
which is clearly equal to ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$, hence is not equal to $f(0,0)$.

Comment: I dont understand the logic if it is a straight line then the restriction of the function is continuous at (0,0) however if it is a curve then the restriction of the function is discont at(0,0)

Comment: @smita: To be continuous at $(0,0)$, it must be true that if $(x,y)$ approaches $(0,0)$ along _any_ path, the limit of $f$ along that path is equal to $f(0,0)$.

Comment: So I tried using the same method to do the next sum which asks me to show that $g(x,y)=\frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^6}$ is unbounded at $(0,0)$.This I have done by taking $y^2=-x^(2/3)$ which will show that the denominator vanishes and also when $x \to 0$ , $y \to 0$

Comment: @smita: Perhaps post that as a new question, showing your attempt. Then ping me in this thread and I'll address the new problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4035462/676808.

Comment: I have attached the link